# perl command line parameter -MIO flag

Tags: shell, perl, reverse-shell

You can create a perl oneliner like this:

```
perl -MIO -e 'some_perl_code'
```

Can someone explain what this `-MIO` means? Couldn't find any useful information about this
(On https://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html there are flags `-I` and `-M`, but this makes no sense for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to [perldoc perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for Perl command line switches:

> -M*module* executes `use module;` before executing your program. This loads the module and calls its `import` method, causing the module to
>   have its default effect, typically importing subroutines or giving
>   effect to a pragma.

`-MIO` is interpreted as the `-M` option where the module name is [IO](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO.html).  This is equivalent to using:

```
perl -e 'use IO; some_perl_code'
```

It does not use the `-I` option.